# SBS 2008 Initial 5 CALs

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, cal

I recently took over IT for a company and I am auditing the number of CALs my company owns.  I have ten 5-packs of CAL sheets.  I know that SBS 2008 comes with 5 CALs.  Was one of those CAL sheets included in the SBS 2008 box?  Or are those initial 5 CALs just assumed and there is no CAL sheet for them?

Asked another way, do I have 50 CALs (10 x 5-packs) or 55 CALs (10 x 5-packs + 5 initial)?

Comment: Not really.  I've read that question before.  It basically says "All licensing questions should be asked elsewhere (licensing professional, manufacturer, reseller).  Doesn't matter where, just don't ask on serverfault."  Does anyone else think that is the lamest answer imaginable?  I realize that answers on serverfault are not official, but I'm sure there is someone on this site who has dealt with this before.

Comment: Well, this is the canonical answer to licensing questions here. It's explained in there why we don't accept this kind of questions, but if you object to this, do it on [meta]. It's a far better use of yours and our time however to just ask an MS reseller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are assumed.  Like you I'm not sure if there is a sheet that comes in the SBS software box (most of my servers come preloaded from Dell or HP with no box), but by virtue of having an activated license key for the SBS product you get 5 CALs.  If you were to get audited they should not need to see an additional license sheet for the 5 SBS CALs that were included.  Total CALs = 55.

Comment: After calling Microsoft, they assured me that this is the case for an OEM copy of SBS 2008.